# How and why (specifically) do EM waves reflect off a surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

why do EM waves reflect? what is happening on the material? could anyone draw me a diagram of how the EM wave of a dipole antenna reflects off a surface?[image]

Comment: https://live-qa.ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/6e5c4b74150da32c3b98964855bbdccb_MIT6_007S11_lec29.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way to think of it: when an EM wave collides with a piece of metal, it induces a current to flow in the surface of the metal which radiates away another EM wave moving in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Model the electric field of a set of charges next to a bulk conductor (say x<0 is a perfect conductor, and x>0 is the vacuum where you have your charges).

From E+M 1, you know the electric field on the surface of the conductor is 0, so the easy trick is to model this problem with a set of "mirror-image charges" on the conducting side that exactly cancels out the fields from your charge distribution. It's a perfect mirror copy.

So now instead of a set of charges, model your E+M wave traveling towards a conductor. This creates a "mirror" electric field on the inside of the conductor that perfectly cancels out your field at x=0. It also propagates towards x=0, which causes the reflection you see.

Additional reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_images